# XAML class extending from base with generic class parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application I want to have some XAML User Controls that extends from a base class with generic class parameter:

XAML:

```
<base:ModuleView 
x:Class="View.ControllerTestView"
x:TypeArguments="local:ControllerTestModule"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:base="clr-namespace:View"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Implementations.Controller.Module">
```

Code behinde and base class

```
namespace View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// View Component of the ControllerTestModule
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ControllerTestView: ModuleView<ControllerTestModule>{ //... }

    public abstract class ModuleView<C> : UserControl, IView<C> where C : AbstractController { //.. }

    public class ControllerTestModule : AbstractController{ //... }
}
```

Without class parameter it worked, but with class parameter and adding the `x:TypeArgument` tag I get the following error message shown by Visual Studio:

```
The name "ModuleView`1" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:View".   
x:TypeArguments="ControllerTestModule" is not valid. 'ControllerTestModule' is not a valid type name reference for the generic argument at position '1'. Line 2 Position 18.    

The name "ControllerTestModule" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Implementations.Controller.Module". ControllerTestView.xaml
```

Comment: Your XAML specifies the class as `ControllerTestView` which is not a generic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic answer: don't do that in xaml.

1. It breaks the designer - you won't have preview
2. You cannot use nested generics like ModuleView>

in your control's in code behind do:

```
public class TestModuleViewBase : ModuleView<ControllerTestModule>{}

public class TestModuleView : TestModuleViewBase
{

}
```

and in xaml:

```
<TestModuleViewBase 
x:Class="TestModuleView " <- and some namespaces
```

That way you won't have to fight against xaml and can use full designer experience. Only downsight is that you need that base class public.

Comment: Okay, I think this way should also work for me. Thanks